# How to disable ion-button shadow in ionic 4?

Tags: ionic4

I can't set the box-shadow property of ion-button to none in ionic 4, so how can I do that for a single button and for all the buttons at once ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
 <ion-button  class="main-button"  >Get Started</ion-button>


    .main-button{
    --box-shadow:none;
 }
```

**CSS Custom Properties**

--box-shadow

--background

--color

There is whole list of CSS Custom Properties in this link https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button

Answer (score 7):

I found a way that worked for me, the below code disables the ion-button shadow:

`ion-button{
  --box-shadow:none;
}`

Comment: Can you explain me why that works? Well I read it in the doc. But what's about those -- ?

Comment: If I got your question right, we are simply overriding the default value for --box-shadow with 'none'

Comment: I didnt know what those -- meant. But now I learned that by -- we can override CSS vars. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--* thank you :)